# How to transpile Stylus to a CSS file in Gatsby?

Tags: webpack, gatsby

Instead of having my CSS turned into a string to embed on the site's HTML, I want a regular, old-school, CSS file to be generated, like `bundle.js` I want a `bundle.css` or something like that.

I'm not familiar with Webpack, but I thought that if I put a `.styl` file under `pages/` and set up a Stylus loader on `gatsby-node.js` this would happen magically, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import styles for them to be added to your site.

E.g. here in the default gatsby starter importing a scss file https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/blob/24f3536420f8cab56dc27a5ce6a78ea894cadae1/pages/sass.js#L2

Stylus isn't setup to work in Gatsby by default.

To add support for it, you'll need to modify the Webpack config to add support for a Stylus Webpack loader. There's instructions on the Gatsby README on how to do this: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby#how-to-use-your-own-webpack-loaders

Unless you're really in love with Stylus though, it might be easier to use one of the built-in styling preprocessors e.g. Sass/SCSS, Less, or PostCSS.

Comment: But what will happen with the transpiled CSS? Will it be saved on a file?